# Can I access the tail of the Netty event loop task queue?

Tags: netty

My specific question:

Is there any combination of subclassing and/or composition that will let me get access to the tail of the [task queue](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoop.html#newTaskQueue-int-) housed by a single threaded executor running the Netty event loop?

If I could subclass `NioEventLoop` I think I could get there.  But `NioEventLoop` is `final`.

The context:

In Netty, you can `submit()` a task via an `EventExecutor` so that it will be executed on the event loop.  Naïvely, I want to keep the task size down by detecting if the last submission was one of mine, and, if so, consolidating it with the new submission.

Comment: I don't think you can do this like you planned, and even if you could, it would require synchronization that would kill your service performance. Maybe try to batch/consolidate submissions on the handler side where it's single threaded, or pass a job queue to the task you're submitting instead.

Comment: In case it matters, I wasn't planning on (directly) using synchronization, but performing the consolidation on the event loop as well; should be a quick `final boolean` check.  But it sounds like even though `NioEventLoop`'s `newTaskQueue` method is `protected`, `NioEventLoop` is `final` so I can't actually specify a different kind of task queue.  Oh well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to do this in the next netty release (4.1.37.Final) as you will be able to inject a `EventLoopTaskQueueFactory`:

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/9247

The release should be out next week.